# How R multiples vectors that are not compatible for multiplication

Tags: r, vector-multiplication

When I submit this code to R:

```
x <- c(1,2,4)
z <-  c(7,6,3)
a <- x * z
```

I get:

```
a
[1] 7 12 12
```

So R just multiples element by element. But the two vectors are not compatible for multiplication because the first one has three columns and the second one does not have three rows.

What is happening internally?

Comment: What's happening internally is: each element of vector `x` is multiplied with the corresponding element at the same position in the other vector `z`..

Comment: You don't have any columns or rows there.  They are dimensionless vectors (i.e. they have no `dim` attribute).

Comment: A vector only has one dimension; you're under the impression it has got two.  See @lukeA 's comment above.^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Please note that these are vectors; not tables.

This means they can of course be multiplied with each other and would give the expected result through their inner product.

Comment: Even if they were matrixes, * would still multiply element by element. %*% would be needed for matrix multiplication